# Fastest way to write to a txt file in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have an odd situation: I have inherited a project which has a number of Python processes running concurrently doing various things. These processes are spun-up independently of each other; multiprocessing/threading isn't involved.

I'd like to add some functionality where they write to a single text file with a one-line update when certain events occur, which I can then parse much later on (probably on a separate server) to gather statistics.

I'm looking for a way to append this line to the file that won't cause problems if one of the other processes is trying to do the same thing at the same time. I don't want to add any other software to the stack if possible.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you have a single process writing out whose queue you feed?

Comment: Take a look to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18412844/3315914

Comment: os.system('echo "' + text + '" > '+ fileName)

One of many ways :)

Comment: Multiple processes spun up independently writing to the same file ... and multiprocessing isn't involved?

Comment: @cmd: yes; these processes do different, distinct actions but the processing is related. Some are Python 2.6 (due to dependencies), some are Python 2.7. They're managed by a separate server daemon.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you may want to try using a [file lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking):

```
lock = FileLock("/some/file/or/other")
while not lock.i_am_locking():
    try:
        lock.acquire(timeout=60)    # wait up to 60 seconds
    except LockTimeout:
        lock.break_lock()
        lock.acquire()
print "I locked", lock.path
lock.release()
```

http://pythonhosted.org/lockfile/lockfile.html#filelock-objects

Answer (score 1):

Use queue http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue. All your processes can put data to queue and one of them get data and write to file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single file writing process and have the others queue messages for it to write.  This could be by event raising, message queues, pyro, publish, your choice!

Answer (score 0):

The [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module is thread-safe by design, it's in the standard library and can write to files.