# python multiprocessing writing to shared file

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, file-writing

When writing to an open file that I have shared via passing it to a worker function that is implemented using multiprocessing, the files contents are not written properly.  Instead '^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^' is written to the file.

Why would this happen?  Can you not have many multiprocessing units writing to the same file?  Do you need to use a Lock?  A Queue?  Am I not using Multiprocessing correctly or effectively?

I feel like some example code might help, but please just refer to it as a reference of me opening a file and passing the open file via multiprocessing to another function that does writing on that file.

Multiprocessing file:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class PrepWorker():
    def worker(self, open_file):
        for i in range(1,1000000):
            data = GetDataAboutI() # This function would be in a separate file
            open_file.write(data)
            open_file.flush()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    open_file = open('/data/test.csv', 'w+')
    for i in range(4):
        p = mp.Process(target=PrepWorker().worker, args=(open_file,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
        print '{0}.exitcode = {1}' .format(j.name, j.exitcode)   
    open_file.close()
```

Comment: "There are probably details in these code examples that are not needed." [MCVE]

Comment: Where do the "`^@`"'s come from? I cannot see anything like this in the code. Are these literals or a representation of control symbols?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I have no idea where the ^@ values are coming from...  Every line that is written while running this, is written as those repeating symbols.  If I change the range to 1 and just run 1 processor, the data is written perfectly.

Comment: @ccdpowell: what happens if the PrepWorkers each write a fixed character (determined at random by each worker)?

Comment: @ccdpowell but you can see the file in hex to answer the 2nd question.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I can view the file I am writing to using the terminal command less.  That is how I see the ^@ symbols.

Comment: Ha! `less` replaces nonprintable characters (to, well, let you see them). Use `xxd` to see their actual ASCII codes.

Comment: Based on @user's question, I ran the random string and was able to clarify the problem a little more.  Each ^@ is written where there should be a character written for every process EXCEPT the last one.  In my Example, if I ran this with 4 processors, each processing 10 items, I would have a string of 30 '^@' followed by 10 readable characters.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeez, Didn't know that about less!  ha.  The ^@ symbols show up as periods and are labeled 0000 when viewed using xxd.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412776/concurrent-writing-to-the-same-file-using-threads-and-processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would this happen?

There are several processes which possibly try to call

```
open_file.write(data)
open_file.flush()
```

at the same time. Which behavior would be fitting, in your eyes, if something like

- a.write
- b.write
- a.flush
- c.write
- b.flush

happens?

> Can you not have many multiprocessing units writing to the same file? Do you need to use a Lock? A Queue?

[Python multiprocessing safely writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file) recommends having one queue, which is the read by one process which writes to the file. So do [Writing to a file with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524635/writing-to-a-file-with-multiprocessing) and [Processing single file from multiple processes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196367/processing-single-file-from-multiple-processes-in-python).

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I needed.  I was trying to do too much with the data the processes were overlapping writing in between flushing.  This problem stemmed from a fundamental mis-understanding of how to structure multiprocessing jobs.

Comment: Why does using a Lock for preventing the write/flush from different processes interweaving not work?  I distribute counters using the approach described here and figured the same approach should work for an open file.  http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Comment: @ccdpowell: The code at the website you linked to seems fine. Without looking at yours, it's hard to say.How about you ask a new question with the modified code? (Feel free to ping this comment if it's not immediately answered)